# Can different methods of a class instance be called from multiple airflow tasks?

Tags: airflow

I'm having difficulty implementing airflow workflow.

There is a class which is for making data with several steps.
Steps are implemented as methods in a class and I need to run this on Ariflow.
This is the example.

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.df = pd.DataFrame()
    def A1():
        dataRepoDAO = DataRepoDAO()
        self.df = dataRepoDAO.load_data() --> oracle connection
     def A2():
        condition = ()
        self.df = self.df.loc[condition]
     def A3():
        condition = ()
        self.df = self.df.loc[condition]
```

In this case I need to call this methods in sepereated airflow tasks to monitor each one.
Is there any good way to do this?
When I call A2 after A1 calling, self.data_df is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup, passing a DataFrame's state around for different layers of transformations.

I saved the DataFrame to Cloud Storage, for example, S3 buckets and other iterations saved the processing data to a DB table.

The next task in the process, first retrieves the previous state to modify.

Here are couple of examples which you might find useful:
**Option 1 - Loading a static path using the params key/value**

```
import airflow
from airflow import DAG

with DAG(
    dag_id="example_dag",
    params={"file_path": "S3 Path"}
) as dag:

    class A:
        def __init__(self):
            self.df = pd.DataFrame()
        def A1():
            self.df = pd.read_csv(params["file_path"])
```

**Option 2 - Mixin the filename/path, and utilise it within the op_kwargs**

```
with DAG(
    dag_id="example_dag",
    params = {
        "file_name": "df.csv"
    }
) as dag:

    t1 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="task_1",
        python_callable=task_1,
        op_kwargs={"file_name": "{{ params.file_name }}"}
    )

    t2 = PythonOperator(
        task_id="task_2",
        python_callable=task_2,
        op_kwargs={"file_name": "{{ params.file_name }}"}
    )

    t1 >> t2
```

**Option 3 - Depending on your data size you can also save to XCOMs**
[Here is a reference to the documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/xcoms.html)

You can `.xcom_push`  or `xcom_pull`  data from XCOMs, for example:

```
# This retrieves an XCOM from the latest Task Instance of 'pushing_task'.
value = task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='pushing_task')
```

In a similar setup I have, I am appending "_bronze", "_silver" etc. to my outbound file paths, to receive the correct level of transaction in the next task.

Comment: Oh!  I'm sorry I'm late to response. Very thanks for your advice. I'll check and apply it!